# Using OpenCTI, with SF Classic, can I close a call center in another tab?

Tags: opencti, call-center

That title doesn't really fit the bill but I couldn't think of a really good title that didn't just ask the whole question.

I have written a call center for Salesforce Classic using OpenCTI. It works fine; pops to the right page if there's only one matching phone number, shows a page with all the choices if there are multiple matches, and pops to a new Contact, Lead or Account (based on the user's Salesforce-defined preferences) if there's no matching phone number anywhere.

When a call comes in, my call center displays the phone control in a modal in the framed-in space SF allots us. If the user has their Salesforce preferences set to open pops in a new tab, my call center phone control opens on that tab but it also stays open in the initial tab. If I hang up from the call in the second tab, the phone controls in the first tab look like there's still a call in progress, although there is not really.

I'm just wondering if there's any hook or feature in OpenCTI that would let me tell the phone control in the first tab that it's no longer needed and can shut down.

Answer (score 0):

I have used in my project something to communicate information between my different opened tabs: [tabex](https://github.com/nodeca/tabex). You can use it as a simple pub/sub between the different tabs of your application.